# Solr facet column with a condition

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have following facet query which is working fine. However as you can see I need from_usa as one more parameter, I have a country column and it needs to be conditional. Would that be possible ? I cant not use fq filters in this case.

```
{
            "facet":{
                "total_game_plays" : "count",
                "unique_game_players" : "unique(uuid)",
                "total_play_time":"sum(play_time)",
                //"from_usa": "unique(where country=US)"
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the JSON facet API from the syntax you've provioded, so a [JSON facet query should do what you want](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-facet-api.html#query-facet):

```
"from_usa": {
  "type": "query",
  "q": "country:US"
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Would it also be possible to do unique  on that query ?

Comment: I'm not sure what unique would give you? It's the number of unique documents that has that term under that specific bucket. If you want the unique terms for a field that only contains `us`, then you'd get 1. If you want to apply further facets based on counting other unique terms, build sub-facets under that one again.

Comment: Sorry wrong example, created seperate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74495218/solr-json-facet-query-unique-for-particular-values