# Solr json facet query, unique for particular values

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I have following query , For the two company ids, I would also like to get the unique rows (unique_internal_plays and unique_external_plays). Is that possible ?

```
{
    "facet":{
        "unique_viewers" : "unique(uuid)",
        "internal_plays": {
            "type": "query",
            "q": "company:100"
        },
        "external_plays": {
            "type": "query",
            "q": "-company:100"
        },
       "unique_internal_plays": {
            "type": "query",
            "q": "company:100"
        },
        "unique_external_plays": {
            "type": "query",
            "q": "-company:100"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Which field do you want to get the unique values for? `uuid` there as well?

Comment: unique_viewers returns total unique viewers by uuid. For internal and external plays it gets total docs for company 100 and not company 100. Which works fine. Now I need unique docs (field uuid) for same 2 criteria.

Comment: `"internal_plays": {"type": "query", "q": "company:100", "facet": {"unique_viewers": "unique(uuid)"} }`?

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks, feel free to add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any facet in the JSON Facet API you can further divide the given facet into nested facets. If you combine this with a stats facet (an aggregate facet), you can get the unique count for a field in that specific bucket:

```
"internal_plays": {
  "type": "query", 
  "q": "company:100", 
  "facet": {
    "unique_viewers": "unique(uuid)"
  }
}
```

This will create a nested facet under the facet query, effectively giving you a way to further pivot/run statistics across the set for the matching documents.